Evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}\, dx$
Basically the same as title. First I tried to evaluate the integral directly but was not able to do it. I then tried to bound the function inside the integral and then use sandwich theorem but couldn't find such functions. Is there any particular way to solve these kind of problems? I am fairly new to calculus, so have no idea how to approach such problems.

Maybe you can expand the integral around $x=0$ and integrate the first term then take the limit

$$\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}xdx\overset{IBP}{=}\ln x,e^{(x-1)^2}\bigg|{x=\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}-\int\epsilon^{2\epsilon} e^{(x-1)^2}\ln x,dx$$
$$=e^{(1-2\epsilon)^2}\ln(2\epsilon)-e^{(1-\epsilon)^2}\ln(\epsilon)-\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} e^{(x-1)^2}\ln x,dx$$
and we have the estimation
$$\bigg|\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon} e^{(x-1)^2}\ln x,dx\bigg|<e^{(1-\epsilon)^2}\bigg|\int_\epsilon^{2\epsilon}\ln x,dx\bigg|<e\bigg|\big(2\epsilon\ln(2\epsilon)-\epsilon\ln(\epsilon)-\epsilon\bigg|$$

We have that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}-\frac{e}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}e\cdot \dfrac{e^{(x-1)^2-1}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}e\cdot\frac{(x-1)^2-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}e\cdot\frac{x^2-2x}{x}=-2e,$$
where the second equality is justified because $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$$
Thus, $$\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}\, dx=\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \left(\frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}-\dfrac{e}{x}\right)\, dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e}{x}\, dx$$
The above limit ensures the first integrand is bounded near $0$, so the first integral goes to $0$ when $\epsilon\to 0$.
And for the second integral, $$\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e}{x}\, dx=e\cdot \left(\ln(2\epsilon)-\ln(\epsilon)\right)=e\cdot \ln(2)$$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
Finally,
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}\, dx\to 0+e\cdot\ln(2)=e\cdot\ln(2)$$

By MVT for integrals, there is $c\in(\epsilon,2\epsilon)$ such that
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}\, dx=e^{(c-1)^2}\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}\frac1x\;dx=e^{(c-1)^2}\ln2$$
and hence
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} \frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}\, dx=e\ln2.$$

The integrand is equal to
$$
\frac{e^{(x-1)^2}}{x}=\frac{e}{x}\cdot e^{-2x + x^2},
$$
and
$$
1-2x<e^{-2x+x^2} < 1
$$
for sufficiently small $x$.  So you have the upper bound of
$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^{2\varepsilon}\frac{e}{x}dx=e\log 2
$$
and the lower bound of
$$
\int_{\varepsilon}^{2\varepsilon}\left(\frac{e}{x}-2e\right)dx=e\log 2 - 2\varepsilon e,
$$
forcing the limit to be $e\log 2$.

You may try the substitution $x=\epsilon t$ to rewrite the integral as $$\int_1^2\frac{e^{(\epsilon t-1)^2}}{t}\,dt$$ and using continuity of integrand in both $t, \epsilon$ we can just pass the limit inside integral sign to get the limit as $\int_1^2 (e/t) \, dt=e\log 2$.
